# How can I get this Razer Inc -- Other Hardware update off my computer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I keep getting this pop-up near all the time even after sending it multiple times.

[image]

It seems to correspond with this update highlighted.  There is no KB #, though.

[image]

There is no mention of it in the updates to uninstall it, and there is no program listed for it in programs to uninstall.

[image]

And there's no drivers for this Lycosa keyboard in device manager to remove.
[image]

So how can I get this Razer Inc -- Other Hardware update off my computer?

Answer (score 0):

The RzWizard.exe is software that installs drivers and apps for specific hardware made by the Razer brand, which are usually gaming mouse and keyboards, although Razer also make high grade recording microphones and audio sound systems for PC. So unless you do in fact have a "Razer Lycosa" back-lit keyboard, then it appears that Microsoft is trying to install a driver that is not needed on your system, via Windows Update.  That's why the update has no KB number attached to it, because it is a driver for specific hardware. I have one of those keyboards, they are a shiny black keyboard with blue LED light back-lit keys> In fact the keyboard is so shiny that it is also referred to as mirror.